# Centering (horizontally) content inside Bootstrap carousel slides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm working on a project where we use full screen Bootstrap carousel to display some slides.

The content is mostly images, tables and text. I cannot get the content in each slide to be horizontally centered.

```html
<div class="container-fluid main">
  <div id="slideshowCarousel" class="carousel slide h-100" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false" data-bs-wrap="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner d-flex justify-content-evenly h-100 align-items-center">
      
        <div class="carousel-item w-100">
          [slide content here]
        </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea?
A working example is  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sdonk/gm48vhdn/3/)

Comment: Try to move the `justify-content-evenly` to the `.carousel-item` and add `d-flex`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't work. The content is indeed centred, but the slides are all showing up one on top of the other.